# How to add tinyint to database field in cakephp 3 using migration Plugin?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3 migrations plugin to design database. I want to add a `status` field `tinyint` with limit as `1` to an field, I have tried the following but nothing adds up.

**Attempt 1. (Fails)**

```
$table->addColumn('status', 'smallinteger', [
        'default' => 0,
        'limit' => 1,
        'null' => false,
]);
```

**Attempt 2. (Fails)**

```
$table->addColumn('status', 'tinyint', [
        'default' => 0,
        'limit' => 1,
        'null' => false,
]);
```

I could not find any documentation for the same may be its there and i am missing something [Docs Link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding field type of boolean adds tinyint column of length 1

```
$table
      ->addColumn('status', 'boolean', [
                'default' => false,
                'null' => false,
            ]);
```

Comment: thanks man i dind not think that way cakephp take tinyint 1 as boolean

Comment: You can also add `'signed' => false` to get an unsigned tinyint.

Answer (score 1):

The migration plugin uses the Phinx library for executing these updates. Adding *tinyint* columns should be done with `MysqlAdapter::INT_TINY` constant as follows:

```
use Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter;
...
$table->addColumn('status', 'tinyint', [
    'default' => 0,
    'limit' => MysqlAdapter::INT_TINY, // 255
    'null' => false,
]);
```

Source: [Phinx Mysql Tinyint](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html?highlight=tinyint#limit-option-and-mysql)

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MysqlAdapter' not found in /var/www/html/cake3plugin/config/Migrations/20160122144154_CreateProducts.php on line 35

Comment: You have to add the classes to be used at the top. `use Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter;`.

Fine if N nem's solution works.

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]                                         
  An invalid column type "tinyint" was specified for column "status  
  "

Comment: appreciate the effort though

Comment: There is no `tinyint` type, you'd have to use `integer`, and a length of `255`. While this would create a `TINYINT` column, it would have a length of `255`, which is not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure out how to add a regular, non-boolean tinyint, and I kept coming across this question when searching for an answer.  So for the others like me, it's this:

```php
use Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter;
    
$table->addColumn('status', 'integer', [
    'default' => 0,
    'limit' => MysqlAdapter::INT_TINY,
    'null' => false,
]);
```